# assign name of various dictionaries from elements of a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am generating 7 dictionaries which represent a day in a week. A dictionary is generated from zipping 2 lists. everything is working fine, but there is some redundancy in code which I want to remove. let us see the code first

```
day_names = ['mon','tue','wed','thurs','fri','sat','sun']

time_values = np.linspace(1,23,23,dtype='int') # print from 1,2...23

for day_iterator in range(1,7+1):


    number_of_clients = [] # create empty list that will hold number of clients
    for i in range(1,24,1):
        rand_value =  random.randint(1,20) # generate number of clients
        number_of_clients.append(rand_value)

    if day_iterator == 1:
        mon = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))

    elif day_iterator == 2:
        tue = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))

    elif day_iterator == 3:
        wed = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))

    elif day_iterator == 4:
        thurs = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))

    elif day_iterator == 5:
        fri = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))

    elif day_iterator == 6:
        sat = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))

    elif day_iterator == 7:
        sun = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))
```

so basically instead of using `sun`, `mon` i want to use something like

```
str(day_names[i+1]) = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))
```

Comment: And you want these dicts to float around in the namespace or be aggregated in a list/dict, for example?

Comment: dictionaries solves my purpose in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals), e.g.:

```
locals()[day_names[i-1]] = ...
```

See also [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals)

However, the use of `locals()` or `globals()` is somewhat discouraged. Consider using a dictionary to aggregate these values, e.g.:

```
d = dict()

d['mon'] = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))

d[day_names[i-1]] = dict(zip(time_values,number_of_clients))
```

Comment: it gave me this error,
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: indices in lists start from zero. if `i` ranges from 1 to 7, use `i-1`